# Crossreference two collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have two collections A + B. Both are created at the same event. B is created some lines before A. Now I need to store in A the _id of B. How do I get the id of the just created B? 
I am new to meteor and mongoDB, is the _id internally passed back on creation so that it is already available (I did not find an indication for this) or do I need to reread B? If so how do I do this best?

EDIT

I understand that the _id is passed back on the server after the insert.

Client:

```
 Meteor.call('addB',b );
```

Server:

```
'addB':function(b){
    return B.insert(b);
},
```

How can I pass B._id to the client so that I can do, on the client,  something like:

```
a.id_of_B = B._id
Meteor.call('addA',a );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[collection.insert](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert) returns the value of the created `_id` field. The docs says "Returns its unique _id.".

Comment: Thanks, the collection.insert provides the _id on the server, is there a methode to pass the ID direcly back to the Meteor.call('xx',yy); from the client?

Comment: I guess your question is answered now, but when you do an insert on the client, the client (and not the server) will generate the id for you, so you have access to it directly, and do not need to use methods or similar.

Answer (score 0):

To return the values to the client a simple callback can be used:

Here again the link to the docs [collection.insert](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert)

Client:

```
 Meteor.call('addB',b function(error, result) {
      BId = result;
 });
```

Server:

```
'addB':function(b){
   return B.insert(b);
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in general you don't need Meteor.call() to insert into a collection. You can do both inserts on the client (if the collections are available there) and these inserts will automatically be synchronized back to the server.

```
var a = {...}; // some object
var b = {...}; // some other object


B.insert(b,function(err,id){ // asynchronous style
  a.idOfB = id;
  A.insert(a);
})

a.idOfB = B.insert(b); // synchronous style
A.insert(a);
```